# How to find a button element with xpath?

Tags: xpath

In a chrome browser I am trying to find an element in a page using the add-on [XPath Helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl). In the webpage itself there is the following structure:

```
<button type="button" class="ivu-btn ivu-btn-primary ivu-btn-circle ivu-btn-large">
  <!----> 
  <i class="ivu-icon ivu-icon-md-list"></i> 
  <span class="">Validation List</span>
</button>
```

which I am trying to find with the xpath expression

```
//button/span[contains(@text(), 'Validation')]
```

However, no match is indicated. I need to check if some text is contained, as there might be whitespaces, so I have to use `contains`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close, try this:

```
 //button/span[text() = 'Validation List']
```

or more accurately to match your test:

```
//button/span[contains(text(), 'Validation')]
```

Comment: because text is not an attribute. so you do not want the @, you could have use the @class if you wanted or something but text() is a sub element technically..

Comment: Yes, now it works. And again some simple stuff I forgot. These path crap will drive me crazy. Taanks

Comment: Don't worry about it, we all go thru it.. And when you are too close to it, you will read and re-read it and miss it until someone else helps out.. this is why we are all here :)